# Trying to deploy postgres database but getting psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed

Tags: postgresql, docker, deployment, gitlab

```
  File \"/app/migrations/__main__.py\", line 41, in \u003cmodule\u003e
    run(migrate())
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py\", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py\", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File \"/app/migrations/__main__.py\", line 24, in migrate
    await up(db_url, to=amount)
  File \"/app/migrations/__init__.py\", line 94, in up
    await ensure_migrations_table(db_url)
  File \"/app/migrations/__init__.py\", line 68, in ensure_migrations_table
    async with await AsyncConnection.connect(db_url) as conn:
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/connection_async.py\", line 130, in connect
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: Connection refused
\tIs the server running on host \"10.28.10.150\" and accepting
\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is my build-db-image portion from my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
build-db-image:
  stage: build
  image: docker
  services:
    - docker:git
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    POSTGRES_USER: example_user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    POSTGRES_DB: example_db
    POSTGRES_VOLUME: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    GITLAB_DB_IMAGE: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/postgres
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token registry.gitlab.com --password-stdin
  script:
    - docker run -d --name mar-15-et-database-service.default.svc.cluster.local -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD -e POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER -e POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_DB -p $POSTGRES_PORT:5432 -v postgres_data:$POSTGRES_VOLUME postgres:14.5-bullseye
    - docker build -f api/Dockerfile.dev --build-arg POSTGRES_HOST=mar-15-et-database-service.default.svc.cluster.local --tag my_migration_image:latest api
    - docker run -e POSTGRES_HOST=mar-15-et-database-service.default.svc.cluster.local my_migration_image:latest
    - docker tag my_migration_image:latest $GITLAB_DB_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $GITLAB_DB_IMAGE:latest

    # - docker build -f api/Dockerfile.dev --tag $GITLAB_DB_IMAGE:latest api
    # - docker push $GITLAB_DB_IMAGE:latest
  only:
    - main
```

This is my dockerfile.dev file:

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
# RUN pip install python-dotenv
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
WORKDIR /deps
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
COPY migrations migrations
CMD /wait && python -m migrations up && uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
```

I tried deploying an app named "database" to the cloud, but when I check the logs it returns a psycopg.OperationalError.

```
% glv-cloud-cli deploy -a database \
  -i registry.gitlab.com/wmo90/reel-reviews/postgres:latest \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=example_db \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=example_user \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
  -m /var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -p 5432 \
  -x=false
```

I've tried deploying without running the docker run/build postgres database scripts but it returns the same psychopg error in terminal when deploying "database". Similarly I tried building then running a postgres db within the docker image in gitlab and it is still returning errors when running the migrations to the database. Namely cannot connect to database.